# How can I see the sql statement of a view (db resides on AWS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've just installed the vscode extension (Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code (SQL and PLSQL)
) and successfully connected the db.

The db resides on AWS.

I can connect the db and just wanted to test it by opening an existing view.

But, it just lets me "describe" the view. So I can see the columns but I need to edit the query statement.

What's missing? Or is the problem the AWS part?

I usually use SQL Developer but I'm furthermore interested in backing up the work via git commits. And I like the way "git graph" extensions presents the changes.

Comment: sql developer has a CLI called SQLcl - it has built in liquibase support, which you can use to generate the source behind your view, and since it's a CLI, it makes automation straighforward

Comment: thanks, but I'm interested in editing the view/query WITHIN visual studio code. sql developer is working fine but doesn't have the smooth git presentation like git graph vscode extension.

Comment: sqlcl - a command line interface, there is no GUI. you can run a command to it from vs code to get your SQL/DDL

Comment: Hey Jeff, did you write the CLI? Awesome. Downloaded it, saved in Downloads. Opened bin and run sql.exe. Tried the username/pw I got from my company, then tried the username/pw for the specific database (key/value I connect within VScode to Database). Neither works. The online doc tells me how to use it but no info how to get it running....I'm lost

Comment: SQL username/password@server:port/service e.g. sql hr/oracle@localhost:1521/orcl  No I didn't write it, I'm just the product manager

Comment: When I run sql.exe I see: Username? (' '?)
I just doubt that I have to paste all you advised (e.g......)
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=RWaCBq8DS2yObhrXkQw3qA==)

Comment: you need to know how to connect to the database that has the information you want to get out of that, that's out of scope for this question - start a new question if you'd like and ill jump on that

Comment: I do already have a connection, in sql developer, and in vscode. I just don't get it with the info in sqlcli I got so far. And, I'm not sure if I want sqlcli. I'm looking for something that allows me to commit my queries to git. But what I saw about cli so far is not what I'm looking for probably. In both, vsc and sqldev, you get color highlighting of the query which helps a lot in debugging. a query about 500 lines in just 1 color like cli offers, that's not what I'm looking for. But maybe I just don't get it. thanks however for your infos and time.

Comment: if you're in sqldev, just run the DDL command then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from someone of the [Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/oracle-developer-tools-for-vs-code) I managed to get it working.

Basic query is:

```
select
dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'VIEW_NAME', 'VIEW_OWNER') 
from
dual;
```

So, in my case it is:

```
select
dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'ALL_DATA_WAREHOUSE_BOSTON', 'WHB') 
from
dual;
```

Owner is the name you fill in when connection to the database, which is the key/value pair (username/password).

If you are not sure who the owner of the view is, check it with this query:

```
select owner from ALL_VIEWS where VIEW_NAME ='ALL_DATA_WAREHOUSE_BOSTON';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DDL view_name
```

[image]

Or

```
SELECT
    text_vc
FROM
    dba_views
WHERE
    owner     = :schema AND
    view_name = :view_name;
```

[image]